# Display empty xml tag when Localdate is null in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
class Dbvalue {

  private LocalDate dbdate;

  public LocalDate getDbdate() {
    return dbdate;
  }

  public void setDbdate(LocalDate dbdate) {
    this.dbdate = dbdate;
  }

}

class setxml {

  @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
  protected XMLGregorianCalendar xmldate;

  public XMLGregorianCalendar getxmldate() {
    return xmldate;
  }

  public void setxmldate(XMLGregorianCalenda value) {
    this.date = value;
  }
}
```

Trying to set date as below.

`setxml.setxmldate(Dbvalue.getDbdate)` // here `sextxmldate` will be null since results from DB is null.

I want to display the empty xmlatgs as below even when the date is null

below is the `XSD`:

```
<xs:element name="xmldate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Comment: But why? minOccurs=0 makes the element optional.

Comment: We are not handling the XSD it was handling other team is there any way we can achieve in code

Comment: The "other team" is violating the XSD. Element xmldate using type [xs:date](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) cannot be empty. It's either present and populated or missing.